# Get the Alias of a Linq Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression, alias

I pass through a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` through to a method like this->

```
Process<User>(x => new { UserId = x.Id, x.AccountNo })

private void Process<T>(Expression exp)
{
   // Get Alias ("UserId")
}
```

I want to try and get the alias of the columns, in this instance i want `"UserId"` for `x.Id`

How can this be achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you want to do with it, here's an example to get your started:

```
class Process
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountNo { get; set; }
}

Process(p => new { UserId = p.UserId, p.AccountNo });    

public static void Process<T>(Expression<Func<Process, T>>  expression)
{
    var newExpression = (NewExpression) expression.Body;

    var propertiesAssignement =
        newExpression.Type.GetProperties().Zip(
            newExpression.Arguments.OfType<MemberExpression>(),
            (p, m) => new {ProjectedName = p.Name, RealName = m.Member.Name}
        );
}
```

The variable `propertiesAssignment` will give you the Anonymous property name `ProjectedName` with the original property name `RealName`. This can be refactored into a generic form and you can expand on to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is still on 3.5.
So in the interim I did this ->

            for (int i=0; i< nex.Arguments.Count;i++)
            {
                var arg = nex.Arguments[i];
                var alias = nex.Type.GetProperties()[i].Name;

Comment: Ah. Yes, `Zip` is .NET 4.0 +. Consider saving the `GetProperties()` call in a temporary variable and then access the array by the index.

Comment: var expressionProperties = nex.Type.GetProperties();
            for (int i=0; i< nex.Arguments.Count;i++)
            {
                var arg = nex.Arguments[i];
                var alias = expressionProperties[i].Name;

Comment: @Lee337 Yes. I believe `Type.GetProperties()` isn't cheap, saving the array is a good idea. `Arguments` is already an array, so that's not a problem. Your code is essentially what `Zip` does, minus the anonymous object, but it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you access it via the Body property?

```
var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
```

And then

```
memberExpression.Member.Name;
```

Comment: The expression in itself isn't a member expression, it's a [`NewExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.newexpression.aspx)